# How to read data inside JSON object in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

```
[
  {
    "id": "dcf8df3f8ce5963d7fa8",
    "title": "MySurvey",
    "description": "Guest Survey"
  }
]
```

Above is json data response from api. I've read above json data with `SwiftyJSON` in my ios project as follow.

```
let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
print(swiftyJsonVar["title"])
```

I can't read and print above json data. Please let me know how to read above json data with `SwiftyJSON`.

Comment: Specify your question, as I can read and how to read what it means ?

Comment: Everything almost is here: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response is `Array` not `Dictionary`, try to access this

```
 let arr = swiftyJsonVar.arrayObject
 print(arr[0]["title"])
 print(arr[0]["id"])
 print(arr[0]["description"])
```